# Input can't be read for if command

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got a problem. I wanted to input a string to if command but it always showed results from else. Here is the script:

```
name = sys.stdin.readline()
if name == 'a':
  print('a')
else:
  print('b')
```

Comment: Now  is: if name equals 'a' charcter, then print charcter 'a'. But are you sure, sys.stdin.readline() equals 'a' character? Write before if statement one line: print(name) to ensure.

Comment: @Zydnar printing `name` won't make the whitespace characters obvious.

Comment: maybe print(ord(name))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `name` probably has a trailing newline character. Either strip it with

```
name = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

or change your condition:

```
if name == 'a\n':
    [...]
```

Comment: So, \n change something? Btw, how can i change format like that one? And it's worked

Comment: \n is also a character but invisible, so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strip` function which will remove surrounding whitespace characters from your input.

```
import sys
name = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
if name == 'a':
  print('a')
else:
  print('b')
```